# Google Drive: How do I share folders, so that individuals subfolders are not synced?

Tags: google-drive-api, synchronization, subdirectory, file-sharing

How to share Google Drive folders and subfolders so that users can decide what to sync to their hard drive?

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive's sync software (the one you install on your computer) only let's you decide which top level folders you want to sync. You cannot *not* sync subfolders alone.

You can however share folders in a way that allows your users to put them into the root folder directly. This way, they can unselect them individually for syncing.

Say you have the following folder structure

```
- Project [parent]
-- Planning files [subfolder 1]
-- Execution files [huge subfolder 2]
```

Instead of sharing the `Project` folder to a user, do individually share the `Planning files` and `Execution files` folder. This way, users can link both directly into their `My Drive` root folder.

In the sync client they're now top level folders and can be individually deselected.

If you would instead share the `Project"` folder, a user would need to "split up" the single share, to move e.g. "`Execution files` out of it. This breaks sharing of the latter for everyone.

By the way, Google Drive apparently seems to be able to have a single folder or file in two or more parent folders. This would also allow for a sharing concept. However, the new Google Drive interface, introduced in 2014 (?) hides this functionaliy. In the old Google Drive, you can use "Move to", then hold CMD/CTRL and selected more than one parent.

Answer (score 1):

Good tip, but this doesn't work very well if your folder structure is like this:

```
- Projects
-- Project ABC
--- Planning Files
--- Execution Files
-- Project DEF
--- Planning Files
--- Execution Files
```

A solution might be the hidden feature of adding a folder to multiple parents. You can still do this in the new drive interface by selecting a folder and pressing SHIFT+z. Use that to add all Planning files to a Planning folder.

Comment: I think it still works. Create two shares, `ABC:Planning` and `ABC:Execution`. Users can then 1. create their own folder `Project ABC` and 2. move the `Planning` folder into it. The `Execution` folder can be 3. moved to another top-level folder, e.g. `Not synced` and this top-level folder can be 4. deselected for syncing.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who want to sync only a subfolder not the whole folder with thing inside

here are the steps.

1. assuming you downloaded and installed drive.
2. go to you sub-folder you wish to sync to your computer.
3. click once on folder, so it turns blue.
4. press keys <kbd>Shift</kbd> then <kbd>Z</kbd>
5. a menu will pop up
6. don't choose a place to put since it only syncs main folders (put it in the drive not a folder)
7. on your COMPUTER right click on drive.
8. go to google drive with icon in front of it.
9. choose a the sub-folder you PUT in the DRIVE

reminder when you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> it copies the folder, so any changes you do to shortcut folder that's in your DRIVE is updated to the drive on computer and inside sub-folder.